# Render video with HTML Canvas in red and black&white colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, canvas

I need to render a video with HTML Canvas in red color. Code Below (if doesn't work, try here [codepen code](https://codepen.io/lzheramzan/pen/RMNVPK)). This code add red layer, but I need in first place - desaturate, after reduce brightness and only then add red layer. I tried work with pixels (problems with perfomance), ctx.filter doesnt work either.

[image]
[image]

```js
const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
const video = document.createElement('video');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: true,
}).then((stream) => {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
});

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const loop = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .45)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
loop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multiply` blending mode to knock out the other colors channels. Since you only define red the other channels with be multiplied with 0, leaving them "empty".

Just remember to reset composite mode to "source-over" before drawing the next video frame.

```js
var img = new Image(); img.onload = draw; img.src = "//i.imgur.com/Kzz84cr.png";
function draw() {
  c.width = this.width; c.height = this.height;
  
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  // main loop
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);                     // draw video frame
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";     // change blending mode
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";                         // draw red on top
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";  // "reset"
  // rinse, repeat
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: please, can you solve for me this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311237/make-your-own-filter-for-html-canvas